# How to read the value from the username text box of my login page loaded in the xamarin android web view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

I'm trying to get the value in the user name text box from my login page after the user entered it in a web page using webview in Xamarin android.

I tried using "document.getelementbyid('useranme').values"

but it is always returning null values. Can any one please help ?

Comment: any update? If my reply help you, please remember to mark as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have found the solution for my problem.

I have user OnLoadResource function in webview which helped me to get the datas I was searching for

```
public override void OnLoadResource(WebView view, string url)
{
    try
    {
        view.EvaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('username').value;", this);

    }
    catch (Java.Lang.Exception oe)
    {

    }
    base.OnLoadResource(view, url);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Js call method in C#.

For example, I create login.html in assests folder:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        var username = document.getElementById("ID").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("Pass").value;
        alert("Username: " + username + "  Password: " + password);

        return CSharp.ShowToast(username);
    }

</script>
<title>Untitled 1</title>
```

```
<div id="main" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
    <form name="MainForm" id="MainForm">
        <input id="ID" name="ID" type="text" size="20" />
        <input id="Pass" name="Pass" type="password" size="20" />
    </form>
    <button value="click Me" onclick="check()"> Click Me </button>
</div>
```

In Mainactivity.cs,

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    private WebView webview;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        webview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        WebSettings settings = webview.Settings;
        settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        // load the javascript interface method to call the foreground method
        webview.AddJavascriptInterface(new MyJSInterface(this), "CSharp");
        webview.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //webview.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: check();", new EvaluateBack());

        webview.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/login.html");
    }
}
```

Create C# class that to return value.

```
class MyJSInterface : Java.Lang.Object
{
    Context context;

    public MyJSInterface(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    [JavascriptInterface]
    [Export]
    public void ShowToast(string msg)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, msg, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Please don't forget add Mono.Android.Export.dll in your reference.

More about call C# method, please take a look:

https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript

If my reply helps, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: I have found the solution for my problem.Please see my Answer for the update